# How to send Javascript to href?

Tags: javascript

I've made this little script which takes my embedded video and converts it to a download link, hence the `var src = str.replace("/e/", "/d/");` however, how can I now send this download link into a href ?

```
<body onload="myFunction123()">
    <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-theme-lt mr-2 px-md-5 mb-2" id="demo">Download</a>
                    
    <script>
        function myFunction123() {
          var str = document.getElementById("download_link").src;
          var src = str.replace("/e/", "/d/");
          document.getElementById("demo").href = src;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setAttribute`:

```
    function myFunction123() {
      var str = document.getElementById("download_link").src;
      var src = str.replace("/e/", "/d/");
      document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("href", src);
    }
```

Comment: perfect thanks, didn't know setAttribute was a thing.